# How to get data from an API with username and pass and a dynamic token in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, ssis

I need to get data from an API and transfer the data to a SQL Server database in SSIS. I prefer to do it natively (for example with C# code in Script Component), the problem is the API structure:
API structure: 
1- Authenticate with a static username and password to get a dynamic client token(the token will change every day).
2- Each request must contain that token.

How to connect to API and get the token automatically to handle requests and how could define columns in SSIS?
Many Thanks.

Comment: .Net provides [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0)  for sending/receiving data over HTTP.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static field for your token:

```
private static string Token;
```

if your request wasn't successful, refresh the token and try again (I'm using [Restsharp](https://restsharp.dev/)):

```
var Client = new RestClient("BaseAPIAddress");
var Request = new RestRequest("RestOfAPIAddress", "APIMethod");
Request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
Request.AddHeader("secret token", Token);

var Response = Client.Execute(Request);
var result = DeserializeObject(Response.Content);

if (!result.IsSuccessful && RefrshToken())
{
   //Call this method again
}
```

and refresh method would be somthing like this:

```
private bool RefrshToken()
{
    var Client = new RestClient("BaseAPIAddress");
    var Request = new RestRequest("RestOfAPIAddress", "APIMethod");

    Request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    Request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            UserName,
            Password
        });

    var Response = Client.Execute(Request);

    if (Response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        var result = DeserializeObject(Response.Content);
        Token = result.TokenKey;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```